# user login mysql php multyple sessions when i log in i cant see nothing on home page

Tags: php, mysql, session

I want to make login(php, mysql). I've already made login, register, logout, home.php. The problem is when I login home shows nothing. I want to make two different users to login, after logging in the table must be created named like username.

I want to have multiple users, when they log in they have own table of information, which isn't seen to other users.

my code:

MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` text NOT NULL,
    `password` text NOT NULL,
    `psalt` text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['user']!=''){
    header("Location:home.php");
}
$dbh=new PDO('mysql:dbname=db;host=127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password');
$email=$_POST['mail'];
$password=$_POST['pass'];
if(isset($_POST) && $email!='' && $password!=''){
    $sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT id,password,psalt FROM users WHERE username=?");
    $sql->execute(array($email));
    while($r=$sql->fetch()){
        $p=$r['password'];
        $p_salt=$r['psalt'];
        $id=$r['id'];
    }
    $site_salt="subinsblogsalt";
    $salted_hash = hash('sha256',$password.$site_salt.$p_salt);
    if($p==$salted_hash){
        $_SESSION['user']=$id;
        header("Location:home.php");
    }else{
        echo "<h2>Username/Password is Incorrect.</h2>";
    }
}
?>
```

home.php

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
<?
session_start();
if($_SESSION['user']==''){
    header("Location:login.php");
}else{
    $dbh=new PDO('mysql:dbname=db;host=127.0.0.1', 'root', 'backstreetboys');
    $sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?");
    $sql->execute(array($_SESSION['user']));
    while($r=$sql->fetch()){
        echo "<center><h2>Hello, ".$r['username']."</h2></center>";    
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use your own salts on password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: before using `sql->fetch` you might wanna call `$sql->get_result` or `store_result` and then use the fetch()

Comment: @user5871514, the code shows `PDO`, not `mysqli`. Now that's why I couldn't find anything about it on PDO's pages...

Comment: my bad you are right you have done that part right

Comment: in home.php you have some output before session_start. But session_start should be done at the very first line before doing any output. Maybe this is your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you allowed the option to use short PHP tags from your php.ini file since you're clearly using short tags for home.php but not for login.php. That might cause the blank page problem. Also you shouldn't have any output before `session_start()` function. Try with this:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>    
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<?php
if($_SESSION['user']==''){
    header("Location:login.php");
}else{
    $dbh=new PDO('mysql:dbname=db;host=127.0.0.1', 'root', 'backstreetboys');
    $sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?");
    $sql->execute(array($_SESSION['user']));
    while($r=$sql->fetch()){
        echo "<center><h2>Hello, ".$r['username']."</h2></center>";    
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

Also, wouldn it be better to store all the information you need from the user in sessions, instead of making another SQL query in home.php?

*Login.php*

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['user'] != '') { 
    header("Location:home.php");
}
$dbh=new PDO('mysql:dbname=db;host=127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password');

$email=$_POST['mail'];
$password=$_POST['pass'];

if(isset($_POST) && $email != '' && $password != ''){
    $sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT id, password, psalt, username FROM users WHERE username=?");
    $sql->execute(array($email));
    while($r=$sql->fetch()){

        $p = $r['password'];
        $p_salt = $r['psalt'];
        $id = $r['id'];
        $username = $r['username']; // Username

    }
    $site_salt="subinsblogsalt";
    $salted_hash = hash('sha256',$password.$site_salt.$p_salt);
    if($p==$salted_hash){

        $_SESSION['user'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username; // Username saved into session.

        // Redirect
        header("Location:home.php");
    }else{
        echo "<h2>Username/Password is Incorrect.</h2>";
    }
}
?>
```

*home.php*

```
<?php session_start(); ?>    
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<?php
if($_SESSION['user']==''){
    header("Location:login.php");
} else {
    echo "<center><h2>Hello, ".$_SESSION['username']."</h2></center>";    
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Guys it works! I have on more qustion. Im doing portal where user log in and see only specified data(connected to own table where his inputs are stored).. In same time another user loged in, must see different content. My goal is that different users see their own content. They store inputs in database, after login. user can see his inputs -only inpust specified by user. if some1 can point me to right direction it would be awsome. Tnx for previus answers and help.

Comment: Well good then.. If it works, maybe you can mark it as an accepted answer then? :) There's really nothing different on just showing the information about currently logged-in user. Just do a select statement query where you will fetch all the information you want to display with where clause and give that where clause a value of currently logged-in users' id.